# Dynamically change radio button with select (Ruby on Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new at programming and Rails in particular.
I have a form to create new goal records.
I have a select to chose the goal "Horizon": "weekly", "quarterly", or "yearly"
I also have a radio button, "Due date" to set the goal as for this term or next term (e.g. in the case of a weekly goal: this week or next week).

What I would like to do: is to dynamically update the radio button, based on the selected option of the select.

```
<%= form_with(model: @goal, url: goals_path, id: "new-goal-form", local: true) do |f| %>
  <p><%= @goal.errors[:date].first %></p>
  <div class="field">
    <label class="label">Title</label>
    <div class="control">
      <%= f.text_field :title, class: "input"%>
    </div>
    <p><%= @goal.errors[:title].first %></p>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label class="label">Description</label>
    <div class="control">
      <%= f.text_area :description, class: "textarea"%>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label class="label">Horizon</label>
    <div class="control">
      <div class="select">
        <%= f.select :horizon, options_for_select({"Weekly" => "week", "Quarterly" => "quarter", "Yearly" => "year"}, @horizon), include_blank: true %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label class="label">Due Date</label>
    <div class="control">
      <%= f.radio_button :date, DateTime.current.to_date.end_of_week.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), :checked => true, id:"radio-this", class: "is-checkradio" %>
      <label for="radio-this">
        This <%= @horizon.capitalize %>
      </label>
      <%= f.radio_button :date, 1.week.from_now.to_date.end_of_week.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'), id:"radio-next", class: "is-checkradio" %>
      <label for="radio-next">
        Next <%= @horizon.capitalize %>
      </label>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label class="label">Related goal</label>
    <div class="control">
      <div class="select">
        <%= f.select :related_goal_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@related_goal, 'id', 'title'), include_blank: true %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <br/>
  <div class="field is-grouped">
    <div class="control">
      <%= f.submit "Save", class: "button is-primary" %>
    </div>
    <div class="control">
      <%= link_to "Cancel", goals_path(horizon: @horizon), class: "button" %>
    </div>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I have tried adding :onchange at the end of the select, but nothing actually happens when changing the selected option.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: So you want to...update the radio button to be dependent on the select option.  Why not just use pure javascript and handle things via click event?

Answer (score 0):

Are your radio buttons id'd differently?  They seem to both have the same autogenerated id.  That won't work in javascript.  Down below you set a click event for the select box and depending on what child is selected, you set a radio button checked to true.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   //when select option is chosen, set radio button to selected.
   $("#select").click(function(){
       var option = $(this).children("option:selected").val()
        if(option == "weekly"){
           $("#radio_button_weekly").prop("checked", true);
        }
    )}
)};
```